# How to impose restrictions on derivatives of user defined functions in SymPy?

Tags: sympy

I am working with user defined symbolic functions in SymPy. I want to impose certain restrictions on the derivative of these functions at certain points and have these restrictions who up automatically when simplifying expressions.

For example, suppose that I have the following function defined.

```
class my_func(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, x):
        if x.is_Number:
            if x is S.Zero:
                return S.One
            elif x is S.Infinity:
                return S.Zero

    def _eval_is_real(self):
        return self.args[0].is_real
```

This function is pulled from the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html) and provides an example of how to make this work if I know that `my_func` evaluates to 1 at the point 0, but the docs do not provide an example of how to impose similar conditions for derivatives.

Suppose that it is well known that the derivative of `my_func` at 1 is 0 and I want this simplification to occur automatically. How can I impose this restriction in the definition of `my_func`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation has some [examples](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/guide.html#functions) of that too: the derivative is implemented by `fdiff` method of the function. You can specify what function (`my_func_prime`) it should return, and then implement evaluation of that function.

```
class my_func(Function):
    # other stuff

    def fdiff(self, argindex):
        return my_func_prime(self.args[0])   
        # argindex (1, 2, 3...) is useful when my_func has multiple variables 

class my_func_prime(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, x):
        if x.is_Number:
            if x is S.One:
                return S.Zero
```

Now `diff(my_func(x)).subs(x, 1)` returns 0.

There are always two steps to this: first, the derivative is taken and only then 1 is substituted for x. One can't do it as `diff(my_func(1))`, that would just be zero. Hence, the values of derivative have to be implemented by the derivative itself, not by the `fdiff` method of the original function: when the derivative is being taken, the value of x is  not yet known.